# Arithmetic progression and average of two prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, arithmetic-progression

Let $A=(a_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$ be the sequence given by:
$$
\ a_n = a_1 + (n - 1)d,\quad a_1,\ d,\ n \in \mathbb N,\quad d\gt a_1,\quad \gcd(a_1,\ d)=1.
$$

For all terms of $A$ greater than $\ \varphi(d) \cdot d^2 \ $ either is a prime number or is the average of two primes which are terms of $A$.

Are there similar conjectures to this conjecture?

> Source: http://www.mitbbs.com/article_t/Mathematics/31205723.html

Comment: The Goldbach problem is similar to this conjecture.

Comment: Indeed, this is a Dirichlet version of Goldbach.  The conjecture implies Linnik's theorem with an exponent of 3 or better.

Comment: Also posted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858764/arithmetic-progression-and-average-of-two-prime-numbers --- come on, Mike, you know better than to post the same question to two different sites without linking them.