# A conjecture on the cardinality of minimal mediated sequences

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

For a sequence of integer numbers $A=\{0,q_1,\ldots,q_m,p\}$ (arranged from small to large), if every $q_i$ is an average of two distinct numbers in $A$, then we say $A$ is a mediated sequence.

**Example.**
$A=\{0,2,4,5,8,11\}$ is a mediated sequence.

For a fixed $p$ and an integer $0<q<p$, a minimal mediated sequence containing $q$ is a mediated sequence containing $q$ with the least number of elements. Denote the number of elements in a minimal mediated sequence containing $q$ by $N(\frac{q}{p})$. By induction on $p$, one can easily show that $N(\frac{1}{p})=\left\lceil\log_2(p)\right\rceil+2$. Based on some numerical experiments, I conjeture that this formula holds for general $q$, i.e.,

**Conjecture.**
If $(q,p)=1$, then $N(\frac{q}{p})=\left\lceil\log_2(p)\right\rceil+2$.

Does anyone have some ideas about proving or disproving this conjecture?

If the conjecture fails, is it possible to give a formula for $N(\frac{q}{p})$?

Lower bounds or upper bounds for $N(\frac{q}{p})$ are also welcome.

Comment: This seems similar in flavor to problems about addition chains. While I imagine the estimate is close, I suspect equality does not hold for every proposed pair p,q.  Gerhard "Enjoys The Taste Of Mathematics" Paseman, 2019.12.12.

Comment: You asked a qualified question. This conjecture may helps, see: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173510/arithmetic-progression-and-average-of-two-prime-numbers